# java 6, mysql5.6, jersey not support emoji properly

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, mysql-5.6

I am trying to support emoji in my web-app. I made the needful changes in DB for utf8mb4. When I save this text "hi ", saved successfully. When I check in DB then its display as ? but when I run this script in DB 'SET NAMES utf8mb4' then display the actual text "hi ".

So after that I, made the rest API with JSON obj response and emoji work fine. But When I generate a custom Java obj response then emoji change to ?. Basically, emoji works fine with Jason Response but not with custom obj.

Answer (score 0):

got the issue, while creating the custom object to JSON we are using output stream with bytes. I need to use UTF-8 encoding for byte stream.